# Redirect to a url from action called inside an overriden template in symfony2

Tags: symfony, redirect, twig

I am using ezpublish for a e-commerce site which uses symfony2 as PHP framework. SO basically I have to override all ezpublish objects of type "folder" in full content view(because they do not have any content but are basic containers). When I try to redirect from an action by calling the action in the template as 
 I am trying to redirect , like this

```
{% extends 'MyBundle::pagelayout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {# redirect to home Page #}
    {{ render_esi(controller('MyBundle:Content:redirectToHomepage')) }}
    {% if not ez_is_field_empty(content, 'name') %}
        <h3>{{ ez_render_field(content, 'name') }}</h3>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

and my action is

```
/* redirect to home page on folder full view */
    public function redirectToHomepageAction()
    {
       return $this->redirect('http://mysite.local/');
       /*$response = new RedirectResponse('http://mysite.local/', 301);
       return $response;*/
    }
```

It shows shows me an empty page/block !!

What is the way to redirect from a template ?

Answer (score 0):

The right method in a Controller is `redirect()`. Try like this:

```
return $this->redirect('http://mysite.local/');
```

Comment: Was not working either , I have edited the question for a better understanding !

Comment: Well, in your case, only `block content` is concerned by the specific action. IMO, redirection must be done in the controller. Instead of "calling/displaying" a view, return directly the redirection.

Comment: I thought the same , but the fact is how I "override" / get to know a folder is in full view ? I need to override the object right ? ( For which I have to render a template ) , How do I go straight to the controller action when a folder is opened in full view ?